# Evaluating $\sum_{t=0}^{1000}(-1)^t \binom{2000}{2t}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation, binomial-coefficients

Calculate the sum $$\sum_{t=0}^{1000}C_{2000}^{2 t}(-1)^{t}$$
Please kindly help me or show me how to do this.
$$\sum_{t=0}^{1000}C_{2000}^{2 t}(-1)^{t}=\sum_{t=0}^{1000}C_{2000}^{2 t}(i)^{2t}$$
$$\Rightarrow\sum_{t=0}^{1000}C_{2000}^{2 t}(-1)^{t}=(1+i)^{2000}=2^{1000}$$
Please kindly check my answer.
I mean $C_{n}^{r}=C(n,r)$, $r$ is smaller or equal than $n$
Thank in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:complex-numbers]?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: How is this a geometric series?

Comment: Wait, what does that notation mean? I am interpreting it as $\sum_{t=0}^{1000}(-1)^t\binom{2t}{2000}$. @A-LevelStudent

Comment: @LightYagami Oh, perhaps you're right, I just interpreted it as some variable $C$ with a random subscript. I've never seen binomial coefficients being represented as that; is that notation standard?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation).

Comment: @LightYagami thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah Can you check my answer?

Comment: I have typed it in.

Comment: Is $C^{2t}_{1000}=\binom{2t}{1000}$, the binomial coefficient, or something else? Is it possibly upside-down: $\binom{1000}{2t}$?

Comment: @PetterGreen please can you clarify what $C_{2000}^{2t}$ means? Is it a binomial coefficient? If so, which binomial coefficient?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Yeah it is a binomial coefficient.

Comment: @PetterGreen so do you mean the binomial coefficient $\binom{2t}{2000}$? That seems a bit odd.

Comment: Yeah it mean $C(2000,2t)$

Comment: From the added work, it is apparent that [tag:complex-numbers] seems a reasonable tag.

Comment: @PetterGreen: your answer is on the right track (I take the same track in my answer). One problem is that $(1+i)^{2000}=2^{1000}\ne1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{1000}(-1)^k\binom{2000}{2k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{1000}i^{2k}\binom{2000}{2k}\tag1\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2000}i^j\binom{2000}{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{2000}(-i)^j\binom{2000}{j}\right)\tag2\\
&=\frac12\left((1+i)^{2000}+(1-i)^{2000}\right)\tag3\\[6pt]
&=\frac12\left(\left(\sqrt2e^{\pi i/4}\right)^{2000}+\left(\sqrt2e^{-\pi i/4}\right)^{2000}\right)\tag4\\[9pt]
&=2^{1000}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $i^{2k}=(-1)^k$
$(2)$: when $j$ is even, $j=2k$ and $i^j+(-i)^j=2i^{2k}$
$\phantom{\text{(2):}}$ when $j$ is odd, $i^j+(-i)^j=0$
$(3)$: Binomial Theorem
$(4)$: $1+i=\sqrt2e^{\pi i/4}$ and $1-i=\sqrt2e^{-\pi i/4}$
$(5)$: $\sqrt2^{2000}=2^{1000}$ and $\left(e^{\pm\pi i/4}\right)^{2000}=1$

Comment: Can you explain me how it go from line 1 to line 2?

Comment: The terns with the odd $k$ cancel; the terms with the even $k$ double. We want the sum of the even terms so we divide by $2$.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more or add something in answer more for me .

Comment: I have added a detailed explanation

Comment: Whenever I see an answer with an explanation for each step, I know instantly that it's yours robjhon! Your answers are so incredibly clear, and I have been helped by them on more than a few occasions, many thanks for all your time and effort.

Comment: Thanks. The explanations also help me when someone asks what I did 4 or 5 years down the line.

Comment: @robjohn I think my answer is wrong even it has the same answer right? Because maybe I cannot use binomial theorem to see $(1+i)^{2000}$

Comment: @robjohn Or I can do as my method just I make more explain about the binomial theorem like I let $2t=k$ so that $t=0,k=0$ and $t=1000, k =2000$ so that the expression will $\sum_{k=0}^{2000}C_{2000}^{k}i^k=(1+i)^{2000}$

Comment: Although $(1+i)^{2000}=2^{1000}$, you need to explain either *why* the sum you seek is the real part of $(1+i)^{2000}$, or *why* the imaginary part of $(1+i)^{2000}$ is $0$, or use my argument which eliminates the imaginary part. Otherwise, *something* is missing.

Comment: Thank so much for your explaination

Answer (score 1):

The sum is $$\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{1000}(-1)^t C(2000,2t)=\sum_{t=0}^{1000}(-1)^t\binom{2000}{2t}$$ Now consider the binomial expansion of $$(1+x)^{2000}=\binom{2000}{0}+\binom{2000}{1}x+\binom{2000}{2}x^2+\cdots+\binom{2000}{2000}x^{2000}$$

Now, plug $x=i$ in it and the real part of that expansion is your expansion. Hence, we evaluate the real part of the LHS, we can write $$1+i=\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$$ This raised to $2000$th power is $2^{1000}e^{i500\pi}=2^{1000}(\cos(500\pi)+i\sin(500\pi)$ which equals $2^{1000}$.

Comment: Yeah can you check my above answer.

Comment: @PetterGreen See the edit.

Comment: $1+i=\sqrt2e^{\pi i/\color{#C00}{4}}$. The result is the same, so the error is masked.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for pointing out, I have corrected it. I was writing hastily at that time, that's why didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

You are using non-standard notation. I expect you mean to calculate:
$$\sum_{t=0}^{1000}\binom{2000}{2 t}(-1)^{t}$$

Consider
$$(1+1)^{2000}=\sum_{t=0}^{2000}\binom{2000}{t}1^{2000-t}1^{t}$$
$$(1-1)^{2000}=\sum_{t=0}^{2000}\binom{2000}{t}1^{2000-t}(-1)^{t}$$
Add:
$$2^{2000}+0=2\sum_{t=0 \text{, even}}^{2000}\binom{2000}{t}=2\sum_{t=0 }^{1000}\binom{2000}{2t}$$
$$\sum_{t=0 }^{1000}\binom{2000}{2t}=2^{1999}$$

Comment: where did the $2t$ in the lower index of the binomial coefficient go?

Comment: The odd $t$'s do cancel and only the even remain, but the series does not alternate.